# *Flung* is Intransitive or Transitive?

Tags: sentence-construction, transitivity

*The impact was such that the canine flung into the air and fell into a drain five meters away.*

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/noida/bike-rider-booked-for-dogs-death-in-greater-noida/articleshow/67271321.cms

In above sentence should we use *was flung* or only *flung*?

I think flung is transitive because to flung something we need an object. Hence it should be *canine was flung" is correct. It should be a passive sentence construction.

Comment: I think it is merely an editing error.

Answer (score 1):

The impact was such that the canine flung into the air and fell into a drain five meters away. 
[buzzer, not grammatical]

Correction:

The impact was such that the canine **was flung into the air** and fell into a drain five meters away.

**The impact flung the dog** into the air. [**transitive**]

The dog was flung into the air by the impact.

Principle parts: fling, flung, flung

Fling is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Some English verbs

- work with both 0 and 1 objects
- if 0 objects are specified, the meaning is the subject did, or appeared to do, the activity to him/her/itself, or "something made" the subject do the activity

> The impact was such that the canine flung into the air and fell into a drain five meters away.

This is equivalent to saying "The impact made the canine fling into the air."

Saying "The impact flung the canine into the air" is also OK.

Verbs that don't work like this require passive voice, and you could still use passive voice here if you wanted as well.

> The impact was such that the canine was flung into the air and fell into a drain five meters away.

Comment: Maybe it's regional. "The canine flung into the air." does not sound right to me. (West coast, US)

Answer (score -1):

"Fling" used to mean "throw or hurl forcefully" is a transitive verb, so that "was flung" is needed when discussing the fate of the dog. There is an intransitive use of the verb, meaning (of a person) to "go quickly and angrily", e.g. "after the argument, Peter flung out of the house", but this is not the meaning in your text.

[Fling](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fling)